# Is there a formula to assign a 0 to 5 score by comparing your value against the min and the max of a range?

Tags: percentages, percentile

Lets say I have a database of customers with how much they spent

so something like

Jim 100

Bob 300

Tim 14

Sarah 43

Rob 945

Jake 3,000

etc

What I want to do is then assign each customer a value from 0.00 to 5.00 (so to two decimal places) based on how their number compares to the min and the max.

I think this has something to do with percentiles, but what is the formula to do this?

I guess we would start by separating the data into five quintiles. How do I determine the boundary of each quintile?

And then lets say a customer falls into the two to three quintile. How do I specify the exact two point precision of like 2.13 of 2.67 for their position in that quintile.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you are interested in is where the customer falls within the min and the max, compute $$5 * \frac{customer - \min}{\max - \min}$$ to get a number between $0$ and $5$ for each customer. You can then round it to any number of decimal points you like.

For example, if you only have the data you listed, then $\min = 14, \max = 3000$ and so for Bob you would get
$$
m_\text{Bob} = 5 * \frac{300 - 14}{3000 - 14} = \frac{1430}{2986} \approx 0.48.
$$

---

This, however, takes no account of where the number is with respect to the other customers. If you would like to compute that, then you can compute the actual *percentile* for each number and multiply by $5$, rounding to $2$ decimal places, if you like.

To compute the percentiles from your data set, first sort it:

```
Name   Amount
====   ======
Tim       14
Sarah     43
Jim      100
Bob      300
Rob      945
Jake    3000
```

Since you have $n=6$ data points, divide the $100\%$ range into $6$ boxes, so each box will have $100/n$ (here $100/6 \approx 16.667\%$, and use the maximum (or minimum or middle) block member for each label. Then multiply by $5$ to get your label:

```
Name   Amount  Percentile  Label
====   ======  ==========  =======
Tim       14     16.667%    0.83
Sarah     43     33.333%    1.67
Jim      100     50.000%    2.50
Bob      300     66.667%    3.33
Rob      945     83.333%    4.17
Jake    3000    100.000%    5.00
```